# How do you fetch JSON from Google's Cloud Natural Language API based on existing text using client-side JS?

Tags: javascript, api, google-cloud-platform, nlp

Does anyone know how to retrieve data from Google's Cloud Natural Language (NL) API using client-side javascript? What is incorrect with the code block below - likely line 29?

I've been looking at a lot of documentation today to figure out how to perform sentiment analysis using Google's Cloud NL API. Many of them have not been very clear.

This [tutorial](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-analyzing-reviews-using-google-sheets-and-cloud-natural-language-api-240ec8f3090c) helped me understand how Google's Cloud NL API works to a large degree.

I still have a few gaps.

This is the block of code I derived after looking at a few docs.

**One area I think that may be a potential issue, line 29.**
I've never fetched using two arguments.

```
1  sentiApiKey = ***API KEY***
2  sentiEndPoint = ***Google's Cloud Natural Language endpoint***
3  //dictData is existing JSON data

5  function searchSenti(dictData) {
6     const sentiParams = {
7         key: sentiApiKey,
8     }

10    const sentiApiKeyString = formatQueryParams(sentiParams)
11    const sentiUrl = sentiAnEndPoint + "?" + sentiApiKeyString;

13    const def = dictData[0].shortdef[0]
14    const dict = {
15        language: 'en-us',
16        type: 'PLAIN_TEXT',
17        content: def
18    };

20    const nlApiData = {
21        document: dict,
22        encodingType: 'UTF8'
23    };

25    const nlCallOptions = {
26        method: 'post',
27        contentType: 'application/json',
28        payload: JSON.stringify(nlApiData)
29    }

31    fetch(sentiUrl, nlCallOptions)
32    .then(response => {
33        if (response.ok) {
34            return response.json();
35        }
36        throw new Error(response.statusText);
37    })
38    .then(sentiData => parseSenti(sentiData))
39    .catch(err => {
40        $("#error-message").removeClass("hidden");
41        $("#js-error-message").text(`Something went wrong with the 
          Sentiment API: ${err.message}`);
43    });
44 }

46 function parseSenti(sentiData) {
47    const data = JSON.parse(sentiData);
48    const sentiment = 0.0;

50    if (data && data.documentSentiment && data.documentSentiment.score){
51       sentiment = data.documentSentiment.score;
52    }

54    console.log(sentiment);
55 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago, I learned that there is no way to use Google's Cloud Natural Language API using client-side JS.

Here's some documentation that will help you use client-side JS for sentiment analysis:
http://www.gtlambert.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-sentimoodjs
https://github.com/thinkroth/Sentimental

Cheers.